# "Don't/Won't/Wouldn't want to"

Tags: word-choice, grammar

When do we use each of the following?

> I don't want to ...
>
> I won't want to ...
>
> I wouldn't want to ...

Answer (score 5):

*Don't* means *do not*, *won't* means *will not*, and *wouldn't* means *would not*.

> I don't want to do X.

This per se means you **currently** don't want to do it; however, for a native speaker, if X is defined to be a future event, it can mean "would not" (e.g. *I don't want to do X even if I get the chance*).  However, for a native speaker, a more natural-sounding way to say this would be "I don't think I'll want to do X."

> I won't want to do X.

This means that as far as you now know, **when** in future the chance comes to you, you will not want to do it.  It implies that the chance will at least probably come.

> I wouldn't want to do X.

This means **if** in future the chance comes to you, you will not want to do it.  It implies that the chance might not ever come.  *Would* is usually qualified with an "if" clause, e.g:

> If I ever was given the choice, I would not want to do X.

Comment: It may be worth mentioning that native speakers probably don't use "won't want to do..." for most future situations. Consider: "I don't want to go skydiving even if we get the chance when we're on vacation", or "I don't think I'll want to go skydiving..." are probably more likely utterances than, "I won't want to go skydiving..."

Comment: How's the edit?

Comment: In many/most usages concerning *want*, I think people don't care that much about present/conditional/future tense, because the "I" of now and of the future are assumed to be *the same person, whose choices remain constant*. There's also the implied 'hesitancy/deference/politeness' of common usages like *"I wouldn't want to trouble you, but..."* instead of *"I don't want to..."*.

Comment: @learner: you can accept the answer by clicking the check mark underneath the vote number of the answer.  Thanks!